# Neural Networks for Image Classification (OpenCV/Emgu)

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, neural-network, emgucv

I am new to neural networks and have looked over the (sparse) code samples on emgu and on the forum. However could not figure out how to classify a images using the neural network implementation in OpenCV.

e.g.

1. Categories: vehicles (subcategories: cars, motorcycles, trucks etc.),
   buildings: houses, skyscrapers, huts etc.),
          people: men, women etc.) 
          animals: dogs, cats, tigers etc.

Could someone provide some code samples or pointers? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you want to classify images into a complete hierarchy right away? I don't know OpenCV's learning code, but you might have more success if you start out with a more basic task such as "image contains a human face", feeding your NN portraits of people and desolate landscapes.

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to extract features from images - edges, shapes, colors etc. But am clueless about ANNs, how to design one and go about it. Hence need a starting point.

Comment: This project does exactly what you want:
[Automatic Linguistic Indexing of Pictures (ALIP)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/alip.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your task is beyond the current state of the art in image classification. Practice with something much, much simpler, like [digit recognition](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/NeuralNetRecognition.aspx).

Also, check the [ASIRRA](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/asirra/) project for the cat/dog classification problem.

Comment: I think this thread begs to differ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559843/what-problems-have-you-solved-using-artificial-neural-networks  there's some amazing stuff done with NN

Comment: @NeilN, that thread lists some great ANN uses — I have seen it before and thanks for linking to it.

Comment: Hi Don, I don't believe that this task is beyond the ability of a NN and current state of the art image processing abilities. With adequate although severely complex pre-processing and feature matching algorithms this type of image processing is indeed possible. I've read papers in military research backgrounds that have such capabilities. However I think you are right in suggesting that this process may be beyond most, there would have to be substantial financial and time investment in achieving such an application. Cheers

Comment: Ohh..didn't realize this was that hard. Especially considering CBIR is an active research area (qv. like.com etc.)

Answer (score 4):

If you choose to get your feet wet with digit recognition, here's the [dataset](http://ai.stanford.edu/%7Ebtaskar/ocr/) that both courses I took used for the first assignment in Neural Networks.

Answer (score 0):

Concurring completely with [Don Reba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699711/neural-networks-for-image-classification-opencv-emgu/7699967#7699967).  Giving more specifics, you most likely have not nearly enough data to solve the problems you're trying.  In fact, Stuart Geman gave a talk within the last few years that thinking classification can "solve" vision in this way is not realistic.  It was called ["Google and the VC Dimension"](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/geman/Homepage/Some%20recent%20stuff/Google%20and%20the%20Vapnik-Chervonenkis%20Dimension.pdf).

Digit recognitions and problems of that "size" are more solvable with a decent amount of data.